# Make an array filled with numbers 1 to 10000 and then sum all of those numbers

Tags: javascript

How can I turn this into a function that takes an array of any length and gives you the total?

```
var points = new Array(100);
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    points[i] = i + 1; 
}

for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    console.log(points[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function arraysum(arraylength) {
   var arraysum = 0;
   var array1 = new Array();
   for(i=1; i<=arraylength; i++) {
      array1.push(i);
   }
   for(i = 0; i< array1.length; i++) {
      arraysum += array1[i];
   }
   return arraysum;
}
```

Now when you call the function

```
arraysum(x)
```

pass the function some variable or integer for example 1, 15, or 10000.

Comment: I don't see an array anywhere in your code.

Comment: The result will always be `0`

Comment: @zerkms - It'll be `NaN`.

Comment: i didnt think i had to give the exact answer but there it is

Comment: @charlietfl because that's the task OP is solving: 1. To create an array and fill it with numbers 2. To sum them. People, seriously, learning is an **ITERATIVE PROCESS** of solving basic meaningful tasks.

Comment: OP, is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Sort of, just how can I turn it into a function that takes an array of any length and gives you the total? @WildCard

Comment: Shouldn't the function added in the edit `return arraysum;`?

Comment: it absolutely should, ill add to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do get the sum using the for loop itself simply by using a variable

```js
var points = new Array(100),
  sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  points[i] = i + 1;
}

for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  sum += points[i];
}

console.log(sum);
```

---

You can reduce these two operations using **[`fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)** and **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** to generate the array and **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** to get the sum

```js
var points = new Array(10000); // create an array of size 10000
points.fill(1); // fill it with 1 which helps ti=o iterate using foreach

points.forEach(function(v, i) { // iterate the array, you can also use simple for loop here
  points[i] = v + i; // update the value
});

var sum = points.reduce(function(a, b) { // find sum
  return a + b;
});

console.log(sum);
```

---

Using [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**

```js
var points = []; // initialize an array 

for (var i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
  points.push(i);
}

var sum = points.reduce(function(a, b) { // find sum
  return a + b;
});

console.log(sum);
```

---

Also you can do the addition and array creation in single for loop

```js
var points = [], // initialize an array 
  sum = 0;

for (var i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
  points.push(i); // pushing value to array
  sum += i; // summation 
}

console.log(sum, points);
```

Comment: Why should some arbitrary subset of a language be used just because you're newish?

Comment: @rnevius because OP learns the basics of algorithms, ie: how to split tasks into subtasks and solve them separately step by step. This answer is not helpful for the OP.

Comment: The `fill()` is kinda pointless.

Comment: @zerkms, but how can you be sure that all future readers will be newish as is the OP today ? Also, someday OP will not be newish anymore, then he may find this answer helpful.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm not sure about anything, I try to not make any assumptions and not guess. What I know at the moment is: 1. OP is a newbie 2. They are solving basic learning exercise that teaches them how to use loops and basic operators.

Comment: Same question here...why bother with extra loop even if it is `reduce`?

Comment: A `for` loop is pretty self-explanatory, especially for simple problems like this one, and most newbies can at least understand them when they see them even if they're a little confused about writing them from scratch. The `.reduce()` method is not at all self-explanatory: where do `a` and `b` come from? Where does the `return a+b` value *go*? How does that somehow add up the array? Those of us with experience understand, but this answer didn't explain or even link to some [`.reduce()` doco](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: @charlietfl because OP cannot deal with loops properly, so `reduce` is definitely too much for them.

Comment: @zerkms what I mean is why not do the summation in first loop. I fully follow the KISS principal about not using reduce

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        result += points[i];
    }
```

Function that takes an array of any length and returns the sum:

```
function sumArray(arrayToSum){
    var result = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayToSum.length; i++) {
        result += points[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Iterating through the array is not needed any more. Use `reduce` instead.

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher guys, seriously, OP is a newbie - they learn how to use loops. Please forget about `Array.prototype.reduce` for a second.

Comment: @zerkmsHow can you turn this answer into a function that takes an array of any length and gives you the total?

Comment: @coderman929 any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Michael Melin Edited the answer for you to include requested function

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in two loops, but you might as well just do one loop that does both tasks.

```
var array = [],
    sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
    array[i-1] = i;
    sum += i;
}
```

If you want to generalize the task of finding the sum of an array, you can use a function like so:

```
function arraySum(array) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        sum += array[i];
    return sum;
}
```

For those who can understand it though, using `reduce` is a best answer:

```
function arraySum(array) {
    return array.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b}, 0);
}
```

Comment: "I'm not sure why the array is necessary here" --- because they are learning how to program, and it is their task.

Comment: I've added an answer which shows how to make a function that does the same thing when the array already exists.

Answer (score -2):

A very elegant and compact solution is to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It accumulates the array values to reduce it to a single value by applying each value and a start value to a given function, whose return value is used as the start value for the next iteration:

```
function sum (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
console.log(points.reduce(sum, 0));
```

If you need to support older browser (e.g. IE 8) you can use a [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill).

If you need to create the list of numbers as well, you can create it with

```
var points = Array.apply(0, Array(10000))
    .map(function (current, index) { 
      return index + 1;  
  });
```

It creates an array of 10000 elements and assigns each element it's index + 1.